# Error Occurred During Flow Emails

Tags: email, process-builder, visual-workflow, error

How do I tell Salesforce to send 'Error Occurred During Flow' emails to specific Users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To change where flow error emails are sent, go to the Process
>   Automation Settings page in Setup. Then update the Send Process or
>   Flow Error Email To field.
>
> To specify users and email addresses as Apex exception email
>   recipients, go to the Apex Exception Email page in Setup. Keep in mind
>   that these users and email addresses also receive Apex exception
>   emails.

Reference:

- [Control Who Receives Flow and Process Error Emails](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_email_apex.htm)